# how Create a .qcow2 image of KVM VM

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I have a vm running on kvm
I want to create the qcow image of that vm, so that when I use the
Virt-install command with that qcow2 image and iso file I should be able to get the original vm again from which I have created tha qcow2. How can I do it